# Getting Error while Using JSONDecodable in swift4?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, jsondecoder

I'm getting the following error while using JSONDecodable in swift4. `"Type UserRegister does not confirm to protocol 'Decodable' "`

My Model Structure looks like this.

```
struct UserRegister: Decodable {
    let id : NSInteger
    let name : String?
    let email : String?
    let cities : Array<Any>?
    let tax : [tax]
    let username : [username]
}

struct tax : Decodable {
    let deviceId : NSInteger?
    let financialYear : String?
    let country : String?
    let name : String?
    let state : String?
    let taxCode : String?
    let value : NSInteger? 
}

struct username : Decodable {
    let email : String?
    let phone : String?
}
```

Comment: You do not have a type `xxxxx` anywhere in your code, so I doubt that the error says what you say it says.

Comment: Edited the question now.

Comment: Also please start names of types, such as `tax` and `username`, with a capital letter: Tax, Username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `Array<Any>`. You need an array of some Decodable type, such as String or Int.

Comment: Tried this but still getting the same error, Converted NSInteger to Int.

Comment: @matt + @Zac24 also that `Array<Any>`

Comment: @staticVoidMan Yeah, that alone was it, as it turns out.

Comment: Yeah, this fixed it.

Comment: I know that we disagree on whether to close vote *and* answer a question – but (assuming that the close vote was yours): If OP has edited the question and you answer it, then why don't you retract the closing vote?